# Regex get id from enclosed brackets

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I was fetching data from Microsoft regarding their plans, here's the webpage for reference of data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference#feedback

I'm working on table data to fetch the respective products with their guid initially for the first column it was easy but for the last, they were just using break tags in it. Here's my code for it.

```
import requests
from requests.api import head
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference#feedback"

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find( "table" )
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df = df.drop(labels=['Service plans included'],
  axis='columns')
json_dict = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
regex = r"([A-Z ]+ \(.*?\))"
microsoft_processed_data = []
for item in json_dict:
    plan_data = item["Service plans included (friendly names)"]
    matches = re.findall(regex, plan_data)
    dict = {}
    for match in matches:
        dict_key = match.split("(", )[1]
        dict_key = dict_key.replace(")", "")
        dict_value = match.split(" (")[0]
        print(dict_key + " : " + dict_value)
        dict[dict_key] = dict_value
    item["Service plans included (friendly names)"] = dict
    microsoft_processed_data.append(item)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(microsoft_processed_data, f, indent = 4)
```

It worked till they started using brackets in their plan names as well and my regex failed which was working in a group.

If we consider this sample row out of all

> EXCHANGE ONLINE (PLAN 1) (9aaf7827-d63c-4b61-89c3-182f06f82e5c)

then as per my regex, it was picking up text starting from the beginning to the end of closed brackets.

so, my regex my picked up data till > EXCHANGE ONLINE (PLAN 1)

But I'm looking to get the data till the guid id of it and then separate the name for dictionary.

Here's my sample Expected Dictionary

```
{
    "EXCHANGE ONLINE (PLAN 1)" : "9aaf7827-d63c-4b61-89c3-182f06f82e5c"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`([A-Z,0-9,\-,\(,\),\s\+\s*\(.*?\))`

This regex works just perfect if anyone looks at the dataset as well in the future of Microsoft Office 365 Licenses then use this in your crawler to get all sublicenses in each license type.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `regex = r"([A-Z ]+ \(.*?\))\s*\((.*?)\)"`, It will give tuple of the values you are looking for.

Let's focus on `\s*\((.*?)\)` part only

- \s* will match any number of white space characters
- Then `\((.*?)\)` will take any thing between the parenthesis.

```py
re.findall(regex, text)
[('EXCHANGE ONLINE (PLAN 1)', '9aaf7827-d63c-4b61-89c3-182f06f82e5c')]
```

You can directly pass it to the `dict` if you want to create a dictionary out of it:

```py
dict(re.findall(regex, text))
{'EXCHANGE ONLINE (PLAN 1)': '9aaf7827-d63c-4b61-89c3-182f06f82e5c'}
```

Comment: For Some it works, but for most it fails, here;s what i got, it mixed 2 into one.
`('MICROSOFT DEFENDER FOR ENDPOINT (871d91ec-ec1a-452b-a83f-bd76c7d770ef)Windows 10 Enterprise (New)', 'e7c91390-7625-45be-94e0-e16907e03118')`

Comment: You need to provide the sufficient sample data, the regex works fine for the provided data.

Comment: Just updated my complete code along with the request which will give the whole data.

Comment: Adding pastebin link of data
https://pastebin.com/mBwDFf09